# Is there any tool to find at what time of the day hadoop cluster is usually free from load and submit job at that time daily

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I need to schedule a job in our production cluster.I am trying to schedule it at a time when the cluster is expected to be free based on how cluster load was in past 30 days.Oozie doesn't have any feature that supports this out of the box.I am trying to achieve this using some hacks within oozie.

Is there any standard way to find at what times cluster was usually free in the past few days? and automatically submit the job at that time everyday.

Answer (score 1):

[Linkedin White elephant](http://data.linkedin.com/opensource/white-elephant) seems to be the one that you are looking for. Ganglia has pretty good APIs to gauge cluster usage, which you could use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cloudera manager for checking the complete cluster health (if you are using CDH).

There are Cloudera Manager APIs to interact. you can look at that also to get your work-around.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/09/automating-your-cluster-with-cloudera-manager-api/